# Disabling notification also disables toast messages of the app

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-toast

In my android app , I have implemented push notification.My problem is from my device if I disable notification messages for the app, even the toast messages get disabled. Is this a usual phenomenon or do I need to change anything ? Please let me know how can I overcome this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,it's a usual phenomenon.Click [here](http://www.tuicool.com/articles/jAjERnm) but it's in Chinese.Hope this can help you.

In such case,it is need to write a Toast by your self.I can provide a demo but it is not complete.You can do some modification to make it better.

```
public class MToast {
    private Context mContext;
    private WindowManager wm;
    private int mDuration;
    private View mNextView;
    public static final int LENGTH_SHORT = 1500;
    public static final int LENGTH_LONG = 3000;

public MToast(Context context) {
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
}

public static MToast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text,
                             int duration) {
    MToast result = new MToast(context);
    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflate.inflate(R.layout.dialog_toast,null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg);
    tv.setText(text);
    result.mNextView = v;
    result.mDuration = duration;
    return result;
}

public static MToast makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)
        throws Resources.NotFoundException {
    return makeText(context, context.getResources().getText(resId), duration);
}

public void show() {
    if (mNextView != null) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
        params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        params.y = dip2px(mContext, 64);
        params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
        wm.addView(mNextView, params);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mNextView != null) {
                    wm.removeView(mNextView);
                    mNextView = null;
                    wm = null;
                }
            }
        }, mDuration);
    }
}

/**
 * transfer dp into px
 *
 * @param context
 * @param dipValue
 * @return int
 */
private int dip2px(Context context, float dipValue) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dipValue * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

}

And here comes the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/waiting_bg"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/mColor_white"
    />
```

I am new at markdown.Sorry for the format.

Comment: Is there any way that I can show the toast messages even after disabling the notifications from the device app settings ?

Answer (score 2):

Writing some extra information in 2018; might help someone.

So whenever you disable app notifications via system settings the `Toast` messages will stop showing up for your app.
But this behavior seems to be a choice from manufacturers end.

I tested this on Xiaomi, Motorola and Stock android version of which Xiaomi(MiUi) was displaying toasts even when the notifications were disabled.

The solution is to avoid using `Toast`s for improtant information and use `Snackbar` instead. But this might cost you time and money.