# In Android 5.0+,System's Toast do not show

Tags: android, android-toast

In Android 5.0+,disable notifications permission then System's Toast do not show.Does any one know why is it？

Here is the code：

```
Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: check this - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36951147

Comment: I think this should be two different things, why it is so designed, and how to solve it

Comment: thanks  let me see. Rahul

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for creating a new `Toast` class .

**Toast**

```
public class Toast {
    private Context mContext;
    private WindowManager wm;
    private int mDuration;
    private View mNextView;
    public static final int LENGTH_SHORT = 1500;
    public static final int LENGTH_LONG = 3000;

    public Toast(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    }

    public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text,
                                 int duration) {
        Toast result = new Toast(context);
        View view = android.widget.Toast.makeText(context, text, android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).getView();
        if (view != null){
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            tv.setText(text);
        }
        result.mNextView = view;
        result.mDuration = duration;
        return result;
    }

    public static Toast makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)
            throws Resources.NotFoundException {
        return makeText(context, context.getResources().getText(resId),duration);
    }

    public void show() {
        if (mNextView != null) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
            params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
            params.windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Toast;
            params.y = dip2px(mContext, 64);
            params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
            wm.addView(mNextView, params);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mNextView != null) {
                        wm.removeView(mNextView);
                        mNextView = null;
                        wm = null;
                    }
                }
            }, mDuration);
        }
    }

    /**
     * dip2px
     *
     * @param context
     * @param dipValue
     * @return int
     *
     */
    private int dip2px(Context context, float dipValue) {
        final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int) (dipValue * scale + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:background="@drawable/waiting_bg"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/mColor_white"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

- [Disabling notification also disables toast messages of the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722246/disabling-notification-also-disables-toast-messages-of-the-app?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- http://blog.csdn.net/qq_25867141/article/details/52807705

Comment: must add credits if you are pasting some one's answer. or add link in the end

Comment: Thank you for your help,This method solves my problem.@KeLiuyue

Answer (score 0):

if this isn't the solution to your problem, but I accidentally unchecked the 'Show notification' setting of the application once. It may be an idea go into your device settings/application/manager and check this setting.

Comment: Thanks for your help,but I am a Android Devoleper, may be your solution can not solve my problem